# Gson serializing/deserializing Class that implements list with other variables

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, gson, deserialization

I'm trying to make a class that implements list like so:

```kotlin
open class FixedList<T> : ArrayList<T> {

   lateinit var fixedSize: Int = ...

   var removeFrom: FixedListLocation = FixedListLocation.END
   ...
}
```

But for serializing/deserializing through Gson it will only give me the elements of the ArrayList. Is there a way to set it up so that the two variables are also included? If possible, without using Gson's serializer and deserializer.